# Changes made to CSS, JS not working

Tags: php, host

I just change my css and js file then upload, but the changes do not show up in the browser. But, if i download that same file to my desktop and open it in a text editor, the changes are there.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the browser cache?

Comment: Do `ctrl+f5` to reload page

Comment: Yes, I tried deleting browser cache and also ctrl+f5, but not working.
Also checking different browser.

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing the same problem about 1 year ago. It can not solve by deleting browser cache. Then i was thinking that is the problem of hosting provider and i contact them. After then they solved this.

So i think you should contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading to wrong server (directory) or you are testing in wrong URL.

Comment: Perhaps it is my domain problem, because of it works another domain.